# Z_3: left id proof

Tags: coq

I am close to ending the proof for Z_3 left id. Here is what I have so far

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.
Require Import Coq.Bool.Bool.
Require Import Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.

Record Z_3 : Type := Z3
{
  n :> nat;
  proof : (Nat.ltb n 3) = true
}.

Proposition lt_0_3 : (0 <? 3) = true.
Proof.
  simpl. reflexivity.
Qed.

Definition z3_0 : Z_3 := (Z3 0 lt_0_3).

Proposition lt_1_3 : (1 <? 3) = true.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Definition z3_1 : Z_3 := (Z3 1 lt_1_3).

Proposition lt_2_3 : (2 <? 3) = true.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Definition z3_2 : Z_3 := (Z3 2 lt_2_3).

Proposition three_ne_0 : 3 <> 0.
Proof.
  discriminate.
Qed.

Lemma mod_upper_bound_bool : forall (a b : nat), b <> O -> (a mod b <? b) = true.
Proof.
  intros a b H. apply (Nat.mod_upper_bound a b) in H. case Nat.ltb_spec0.
  - reflexivity.
  - intros Hcontr. contradiction.
Qed.

Definition Z3_op (x y: Z_3) : Z_3 :=
  let a := (x + y) mod 3 in
  Z3 a (mod_upper_bound_bool _ 3 three_ne_0).

Lemma Z3_eq n m p q : n = m -> Z3 n p = Z3 m q.
Proof.
  intros H. revert p q. rewrite H. clear H. intros. apply f_equal. apply UIP_dec. apply bool_dec.
Qed.

Proposition Z3_left_id' : forall x: Z_3, (Z3_op z3_0 x) = x.
Proof.
  intro. unfold Z3_op. destruct x as [n proof]. apply Z3_eq.
```

Result:

```
1 subgoal (ID 46)
  
  n : nat
  proof : (n <? 3) = true
  ============================
  (z3_0 + {| n := n; proof := proof |}) mod 3 = n
```

I found the following theorems that could be useful:

```
Nat.ltb_spec0
     : forall x y : nat, reflect (x < y) (x <? y)

Nat.mod_small: forall a b : nat, a < b -> a mod b = a
```

Is it possible to get rid of profs in the goal, convert proof from bool to Prop, and then use Nat.mod_small?

**Update**

```
Proposition Z3_left_id' : forall x: Z_3, (Z3_op z3_0 x) = x.
Proof.
  intro. unfold Z3_op. destruct x as [vx proof]. apply Z3_eq. unfold n, z3_0. rewrite plus_O_n. apply Nat.mod_small.

1 subgoal (ID 67)
  
  vx : nat
  proof : (vx <? 3) = true
  ============================
  vx < 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the coercion to execute.  Unfortunately,
by naming the bound variable of your proof `n` and the projection from `Z_3` to `nat` `n`, you painted yourself in a corner.

Here are four solutions:

1/ this one I mention just for the record: you can talk about the constant `n` that was defined in this file by using the file name as a module qualifier.

```
unfold user4035_oct_16.n.
```

user4035_oct_16 is the name of the current file, this is ugly.

2/ you could call a computation function that computes everything, however computation of modulo leaves unsightly terms in the goal, so you could decide to not compute that particular part.

```
cbn -[Nat.modulo].
```

I like this one, but it requires that you spend sometime learning how to use `cbn`.

3/ You can avoid the name clash by renaming variables in the goal.

```
rename n into m.
unfold n, Z3_0.
```

Not very nice either.

4/ Just go back in your script and replace `destruct x as [n proof]` with `destruct x as [vx proof]`, then you can type:

```
unfold n, z3_0.
```

you will be able to use the lemmas you suggest.

Proof:

```
Proposition Z3_left_id : forall x: Z_3, (Z3_op z3_0 x) = x.
Proof.
  intro. unfold Z3_op. destruct x as [vx proof]. apply Z3_eq. unfold n, z3_0. rewrite plus_O_n. apply Nat.mod_small. apply Nat.ltb_lt in proof. assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: I used approach #4 and is now 1 step from the end. Updated the question. Can you tell, how to deduce `vx < 3` from `(vx <? 3) = true`? And vice versa: `(vx <? 3) = true` from `vx < 3`?

Comment: If you do `Search (_ < _) (_ <? _).` you see a theorem Nat.ltb_lt which is great for this.  Just `rewrite <- Nat.ltb_lt`  or `rewrite Nat.ltb_lt` should do the trick.

Comment: Yup, I found it and finished the proof.